# PHP header_remove not working

Tags: php, http-headers

*Scenario*:

1. User requests API page with set `Authorization` header with token
2. Authorize
3. Remove `Authorization` header
4. Redirect to AWS S3 signed url

---

```
header_remove('Authorization'); // Remove header

// Get all headers, should not contain `Authorization` header...
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$headers2 = getallheaders();

var_dump($headers['Authorization'], $headers2['Authorization']);

// string(185) "eyJ0eXAi...oUs"
// string(185) "eyJ0eXAi...oUs"
```

Why I can't remove headers using `header_remove` function?
I must also check if header is still set in other requests.

Comment: You can only remove headers **from the response** if you used `header`.

Comment: Question may be re-phrased as **How to redirect without Authorization header that was previously sent by user**

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but here are few points that you should check:

1. [Official documentation says:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php#refsect1-function.header-remove-description) "Removes an HTTP header previously set using header()." May be, the header that you are trying to remove is not set using `header`.
2. `header_remove` is case-sensitive.
3. [Notes section says:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php#refsect1-function.header-remove-notes) "Headers will only be accessible and output when a SAPI that supports them is in use."

As I have mentioned, I am not sure. So, I would love to hear thoughts from community.